# Convert oracle.sql.timestamptz to postgresql timestamp with timezone

Tags: java, sql, oracle, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

Sorry, but i`m noob and i need your advices.
I have some result set from oracle with timestamptz, i get string value of this timestamptz which like

> 2014-1-10 13.47.56.0 7:0

and then I need put it in postgresql-request in some function which takes timestamp with timezone. How can I convert this this string to timestamp with timezone in java? I tried do something look like
`TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ("2014-1-10 13.47.32.0 7:0","YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM")` but it didn`t work for me. Help me, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a function `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ()` in Postgres. You probably mean [**`to_timestamp()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

I also don't know of a template patterns `TZH:TZM`. You could use the **`AT TIME ZONE`** construct.

And data is quoted with **single quotes**; double quotes are for identifiers.

This works for me:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('2014-1-10 13.47.32.0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')::timestamp
       AT TIME ZONE '-7:0';  -- shift back
```

It would be smarter to output timestamps in ISO 8601 format with `TZR` (time zone region) in Oracle, which is less ambiguous. [Details in the Oracle manual.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm)

Or better yet, UTC timestamps (without `0` offset), which you can cast to `timestamptz` directly in Postgres:

```
SELECT '2014-01-10 06:47:32+0'::timestamptz;
```

Or UNIX epochs, which can be fed to the second form of `to_timestamp()`.

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1389336452);
```

Details about timestamps in Postgres:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for other noob questions. can i use this construction in arguments of some postgresql function? and is there any way do it without partition of my input string?

Comment: @mechanikos: I would export UTC timestamps in ISO 8601 format from Oracle to avoid confusion. Or UNIX epochs. I added some more.